# Projected gradient descent

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I was wondering if any of the current deep learning frameworks can perform project gradient descent.

Answer (score 3):

There are implementations available for projected gradient descent in PyTorch, TensorFlow, and Python. You may need to slightly change them based on your model, loss, etc.

- PyTorch: https://gist.github.com/oscarknagg/45b187c236c6262b1c4bbe2d0920ded6
- TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer (tensorflow, this may be easier to use, you can just use it as a tensorflow optimizer without actually handling the dirty gradients yourself)
- Python: https://github.com/amkatrutsa/liboptpy (constrained optimization section)